# Prevent Nhibernate schemaexport from generating foreign key constraints on has many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, schemaexport

I have a mapping like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.Orders).KeyColumn("CustomerID");
```

Which is causing a constraint like this to be generated by schemaexport:

```
alter table [CustomerOrder] 
    add constraint FK45B3FB85AF01218D 
    foreign key (CustomerID) 
    references [Customer]
```

I have tried adding .NotFound.Ignore() like on a References() mapping to disable the constraint from being generated but this does not work.

Can a mapping be defined that will force SchemaExport to not generate the constraint?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
HasMany(x => x.Orders).KeyColumn("CustomerID").ForeignKeyConstraintName("none");
```

buried in the source is a check to ignore creation if the name is "none"

Comment: Thanks for the discovery!  I needed this to prevent cross-database foreign keys >.< 

For non-fluent users: foreign-key="none"

Comment: In later versions of FluentNHibernate, you use `.ForeignKey("none")` to accomplish this; `.ForeignKeyConstraintName()` is not a function anymore.

Comment: Is there a similar technique to prevent `.UniqueKey("xyz")` and `.Unique()` from being generated?