# NHibernate Mapping Reference without foreign-key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've something like this mapping situation in NHibernate:

```
ClassA
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("rowid").GeneratedBy.Identity().Unique();

ClassB
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("rowid").GeneratedBy.Identity().Unique();
mapping.References<ClassA>(x => x.ClassA).Nullable();
```

When NHibernate generate the database schema it creates a foreign-key between these tables even if I've specified "Nullable" attribute in mapping declaration. Obivously if I try to save my objects I get a foreign-key constraint error and if I remove manually the foreign-key from database, it works like a charm.

How to tell NHibernate not to create the foreign-key script in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm think you should use the `foreign-key="none"` attribute in your `hbm.xml` mapping file.

Comment: Great! You pointed me in the right direction! I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2827246/735864

Comment: You 're welcome. Keep also a look at `not-found="ignore|exception"`: specifies how foreign keys that reference missing rows will be handled: ignore will treat a missing row as a null association.