# Specifying the name of a foreign key column

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

```
public class TransactionIdentityModelMapping : ClassMap<TransactionIdentityModel>
{
    public TransactionIdentityModelMapping()
    {
        Table("TransactionIdentities");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Transaction);
    }
}

public class TransactionModelMapping : ClassMap<TransactionModel>
{
    public TransactionModelMapping()
    {
        Table("Transactions");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Identities);
    }
}
```

`TransactionIdentityModel.Transaction` is of type `TransactionModel`. This means there is a column created called `"TransactionModel_id"`. How can I change this column name?

I have tried:

```
References(x => x.Transaction).Column("Transaction_id");
```

And:

```
References(x => x.Transaction).ForeignKey("Transaction_id");
```

And:

```
References(x => x.Transaction).Column("Transaction_id").ForeignKey("Id").Fetch.Join();
```

These all yield 2 columns, the one I want ("Transaction_id") and the original ("TransactionModel_id").

Do I need to also do something with the `HasMany`?

**Edit** the models:

```
public class TransactionModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For NHibernate
    /// </summary>
    protected TransactionModel()
    {
    }

    public static TransactionModel FromId(TransactionIdentityModel tranIdentity)
    {      
        return new TransactionModel
            {
                Identities = new List<TransactionIdentityModel> { tranIdentity }
            };
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual IList<TransactionIdentityModel> Identities { get; protected set; }
}

public class TransactionIdentityModel
{        
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual TransactionModel TransactionModel { get; set; }
}
```

Yielding 2 columns, this is the SQL being generated if I use the map:
`References(x => x.Transaction).Column("Transaction_id").ForeignKey("Id").Fetch.Join();`

```
alter table TransactionIdentities 
    add constraint Id 
    foreign key (Transaction_id) 
    references Transactions

alter table TransactionIdentities 
    add constraint FK958B77026F5C4B80 
    foreign key (TransactionModel_id) 
    references Transactions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Transaction_Id` is the foreign key to the related `TransactionModel` then you need to change your References statement to this:

```
 References(x => x.Transaction).Column("Transaction_id");
```

This will override nHibernates default expectation for the field to be `TransactionModel_id`

Looking at this question [Prevent Nhibernate schemaexport from generating foreign key constraints on has many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826725/prevent-nhibernate-schemaexport-from-generating-foreign-key-constraints-on-has-m), I think you will have to change your `HasMany` mapping to this:

```
 HasMany(x => x.Identities).KeyColumn("Transaction_id")
```

Comment: Didn't work I ended up with two, one called "Transaction_id" and one called "TransactionModel_id". Is there anything I need to do on the `ClassMap<TransactionModel>` where it has a `HasMany` link?

Comment: @weston could you post your class definitions for `TransactionModel` and `TransactionIdentityModel` please

Comment: @weston thanks the one question I should have asked originally, when you say this "yields 2 columns" where exactly?, when you check the SQL that is being executed? Are you experiencing a run-time error somewhere?

Comment: In the sql that is generated to create the tables I see both old and new columns, see edit on question.

Comment: @weston see updated answer - I did some research and found another question with a similar problem - hopefully my revised answer will work or point you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, that got me on the right track, have edited answer to the one that worked.